# Unable to see my recently installed sticky notes module in zend 2 in action

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Folks,

Recently i have installed this zend 2 extension "http://bigemployee.com/zend-framework-2-simple-web-application-crud-using-ajax-tutorial/" but i am unable to see that in action it seems everytime the default "Application" module is getting called.irrespective of declaring this sticky notes in "application.config.php".

I need to tell few points:
1. i have created this path "/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/public" as my document root so that i can access the file index.php just by using "localhost/stickynotes"
but everytime it is calling the module application's index.phtml file it means always it is pointing to that application module only.
see this url "http://grab.by/w6jW".

1. i believe i have to point my "stickynotes" module like "localhost/sticknotes/stickynotes" but it says 404.

my configuration seems to be all correct. like in "application.config.php" i have laready set it like 
  'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'StickyNotes',
    ),

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance that the configuration is being cached?  By default, caching of configuration is enabled in the application.config.php.  (Make sure the values of 'config_cache_enabled' and 'module_map_cache_enabled' are false, and delete aany *.php files in 'data/cache')

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you have defined the virtual host.

You have mentioned - "`i have created this path "/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/public" as my document root` and using the url `localhost/stickynotes` for accessing the `index.php`"

So your main folder is "ZendSkeletonApplication" and there is a module named "stickynotes".

WITHOUT VIRTUAL HOST -
url would be `http://localhost/ZendSkeletonApplication/public/stickynotes`.

WITH VIRTUAL HOST -
There must some `ServerName _SOME_SERVER_NAME` mentioned in the virtual host definition.

Eg: 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName _SOME_SERVER_NAME
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/public"
     [.....]
     [...]
</VirtualHost>`

So the url here would be `http://_SOME_SEVER_NAME/stickynotes`

I hope it helps someone.